# Elegant ways of handling conditional rendering of multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Say I have a wizard-like view with an arbitrary number of steps:

```js
const StepsComponent = () => {
  const [stage, setStage] = useState(1);
  const stageProps = {stage, setStage};

  const stageMachine = () => {
    switch (stage) {
      case 1:
        return <One {...stageProps} />;
      case 2:
        return <Two {...stageProps} />;
      case 3:
        return <Three {...stageProps} />;
      default:
        return <One {...stageProps} />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {stageMachine()}
    </>
  );
}
```

Are there more elegant ways of handling such cases, other than switch statements or ternary expressions?
If I would have wizards with 10+ steps, then it'd be a real mess to manage it.

Probably I could do something like this but this seems hacky, doesn't it?

```js
const stageMachine = Object.freeze({
  1: <One {...stageProps} />,
  2: <Two {...stageProps} />,
  3: <Three {...stageProps} />
});
```

Also I don't like the idea of invoking `stageMachine` function in return, it is considered a bad practice?

Comment: If the stages are sequential (1,2,3, etc.) you can use an array of components. And your `stageMachine(stage)` function can simply index the array.

Comment: You should probably create an array of stage components & then render the one whose index matches stage value.

Comment: @tromgy Interesting, this indeed might work for sequentials, but what about non-linear wizard with kind of branches and conditionals [start](1, 2, 25, 26, 50)[end]?

Comment: @Igniter, in that case your idea with the object "map" is probably the right approach. And the `stageMachine(stage)` can still index it the same way.

Comment: @tromgy Unfortunately mapping to objects wouldn't graciously handle out of index errors and things like that, what could be done for errors?

Comment: @Igniter maybe something like: `function stageMachine(stage) { return stages[stage] || <div>Error: no such stage</div>; }`?

Comment: @tromgy Wrappers make the whole component quite clumsy :) but looks like there are no other ways of handling this kind of things, at least elegant ones, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
const StepsComponent = () => {
  const [stage, setStage] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      {stage === 1 && <One />}
      {stage === 2 && <Thow />}
      {stage === 3 && <Three />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, I have already mentioned ternary expressions in my question. What if you would have 20+ steps? I would like to skip explicit description of each and every step.